# Python loop decrementing a variable for every iteration

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have this python loop that I keep getting the wrong values. What I want to achieve in this loop is that when the code is run, it is asked from the user to input two variables (variable1, variable 2) using these variable, a loop starting from variable 2

- Do the calculation with the current variable2
- Decrement the value of variable2 by 1 and do the calculation
- sum the result of calculating the first time + the second
- keep doing that until variable2 is 0, but add also the sum of calculation using variable2 = 0

The code is behind please free to suggest me what to do or how to do

```
from math import pi, sqrt
def equation(variable1,variable2):
    calculation = ((sqrt(2)*variable1**(2*variable2+1))/(3*pi))*q(k=variable2) 
    for i in range (variable2,0,-1):
        calculation = calculation + calculation
    print calculation
        

def main():
    variable2 = (input("Enter a Number for variable2: "))
    variable1 = (input("Enter a Number for variable1: "))
    return equation(variable1,variable2)
main()
```

UPDATE: q(k) is used from another calculation not need in this block of code

Comment: title should be "python loop incrementing a variable for every iteration", loops iterate. recursive function has recurssion.

Comment: I don't see where you define `q`.

Comment: check update, q(k) is called from above. the issue of what I want to do is how to achieve the points listed in bullet points

Comment: Reproducible example please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
from math import pi, sqrt
def equation(variable1,variable2):
    calculation = ((sqrt(2)*variable1**(2*variable2+1))/(3*pi))*q(k=variable2)
    while variable2 >0:
        variable2 -= 1
        calculation += ((sqrt(2)*variable1**(2*variable2+1))/(3*pi))*q(k=variable2)
    return calculation


def main():
    variable2 = (input("Enter a Number for variable2: "))
    variable1 = (input("Enter a Number for variable1: "))
    return equation(variable1,variable2)

print main()
```

Although this will of course only work if you have defined `q()` somewhere else in the code, as mentioned in my comment. You can also use your for-loop/range version (use xrange though, since you're on Python 2), then you have to replace `variable2` in the second calculation line with `i`. Your main issue seems to be that you think by iterating over a range based on `variable2`, its value changes (which it doesn't).

Comment: looks good, but do you keep the sum of the equation when variable2 is lets say 4 and for then next run variable2 is 3? i.e. variable2(4) + variable2(3) = ?
this is what I want the output to be, and second variable2(0) also to be calculated in the final output

Comment: …have you tried it? I keep the value by saving it in `calculation` and adding the new results to it.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest you be clearer in what you want as unfortunately your description was not clear.

This is what I gathered you wanted though:

```
from math import pi, sqrt


def equation(variable1, variable2):
    return ((sqrt(2) * variable1 ** (2 * variable2 + 1)) / (3 * pi)) * q(k=variable2)


def calc_final_result(variable1, variable2):
    final_result = 0
    while(variable2 > -1):
        final_result += equation(variable1, variable2)
        variable2 -= 1
    return final_result

def main():
    variable2 = (input("Enter a Number for variable2: "))
    variable1 = (input("Enter a Number for variable1: "))

    return calc_final_result(variable1, variable2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```